# How to have ForEach in view updated when array values change with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have this code here for updating an array and a dictionary based on a timer:

```
class applicationManager: ObservableObject {
    static var shared = applicationManager()
    
    @Published var applicationsDict: [NSRunningApplication : Int] = [:]
    @Published var keysArray: [NSRunningApplication] = []
}


class TimeOpenManager {
    var secondsElapsed = 0.0
    var timer = Timer()
    
    func start() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
            self.secondsElapsed += 1
            let applicationName = ws.frontmostApplication?.localizedName!
            let applicationTest = ws.frontmostApplication
            
            let appMan = applicationManager()
            
            if let appData = applicationManager.shared.applicationsDict[applicationTest!] {
                applicationManager.shared.applicationsDict[applicationTest!] = appData + 1
            } else {
                applicationManager.shared.applicationsDict[applicationTest!] = 1
            }
            
            applicationManager.shared.keysArray = Array(applicationManager.shared.applicationsDict.keys)
            
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine like this and the keysArray is updated with the applicationsDict keys when the timer is running. But even though keysArray is updated, the `HStack` `ForEach` in  `WeekView` does not change when values are added.

I also have this view where keysArray is being loaded:

```
struct WeekView: View {
    static let shared = WeekView()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(0..<8) { day in
                    if day ==  weekday {
                        Text("\(currentDay)")
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            .font(.system(size: 36))
                            .background(Color.red)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print(applicationManager.shared.keysArray)
                                print(applicationManager.shared.applicationsDict)
                            }
                    } else {
                        Text("\(currentDay + day - weekday)")
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            .font(.system(size: 36))
                    }
                }
            }
            HStack {
                ForEach(applicationManager.shared.keysArray, id: \.self) {dictValue in
                    Image(nsImage: dictValue.icon!)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 64, height: 64, alignment: .center)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `@State` is for use in `View`s -- nothing you have here is a `View`

Comment: @jnpdx The variable is being passed to a ForEach loop in a view if that helps

Comment: `@State` is for a property of a view. It's not for use in other `struct` types.

Comment: @jnpdx How can I have it so the ForEach will update when keysArray changes? I thought adding `@State` did just that

Comment: `applicationManager` (please capitalize types, by the way) should be an `ObservableObject` with `@Published` properties.

Comment: @jnpdx making the variable `@Published` and changing it to an `ObservableObject` still doesn't update the view when keysArray changes

Comment: Added an answer that explains the rest. This is assuming that `start` is getting called (you don't show that). Also, I'd get rid of your `static let shared = WeekView()` line in `WeekView` -- there shouldn't ever be a reason to have a static instance of a SwiftUI view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `applicationManager` should be an `ObservableObject` with `@Published` properties.

Then, you need to tell your view that it should look for updates from this object. You can do that with the `@ObservedObject` property wrapper:

```
struct WeekView: View {
  @ObservedObject private var manager = applicationManager.shared
```

And later:

```
ForEach(manager.keysArray) {
```

*Replace anywhere you had `applicatoinManager.shared` with `manager` within the `WeekView`*

Additional reading: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-observedobject-to-manage-state-from-external-objects